# 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql-workbench

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNXSe.png)

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''company'.'employee'( 'fname' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 'mname' CHAR NULL, 'lname' V' at line

I GET THIS ERRR ,CAN ANY ONE HELP ME TO SOLVE

Comment: do not enclose your column names in single quote. CREATE TABLE schema.employee( firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL, lastname varchar NOT NULL, ..) , this is sufficient to create the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use backtics (`) around database, table, and column names.  Use quotes (`'` or `"`) around text strings.

Answer (score 0):

User
You
UPDATE final_chrome_totaldata_sept2022
SET sitemap_date = NULL
WHERE   AND sitemap_date = '0000-00-00';
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND sitemap_date = '0000-00-00'' at line 3

I am also getting this error many times but i solved like this

UPDATE final_chrome_totaldata_sept2022 SET sitemap_date = NULL WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sitemap_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '0000-00-00';